# Why can't vue-test-utils find a child component?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have next code in template:

```
<th
    width="0%"
    class="px-3">
    <b-checkbox
        :value="SELECTED_ALL_TEMPLATE"
        @input="TOGGLE_SELECT_ALL_TEMPLATE(!SELECTED_ALL_TEMPLATE)" />
</th>
```

I want to test, that prop `value` match expected result of `SELECTED_ALL_TEMPLATE` getter and called `TOGGLE_SELECT_ALL_TEMPLATE` after `input` emitted.

Test code:

```
it('Checkbox test', function () {
    wrapper = shallowMount(TableHeader);
    const checkbox = wrapper.find(Checkbox);
    expect(checkbox.props().value).toBe(getters.SELECTED_ALL_TEMPLATE()); 
    //Error: [vue-test-utils]: find did not return Component, cannot call props() on empty Wrapper
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

I found a strange behaviour. Also I have in this page TableTh child component:

```
  <TableTh width="10%" 
       :sorting.sync="ordering.id" 
       :ordering-obj="ordering"> 
       {{ $t.certs.table.codeOfTemplate }} 
  </TableTh>
```

and this test passed:

```
  it('TableTh props', function () { 
    const th = wrapper.find(TableTh); 
    expect(th.props().sorting).toBe(wrapper.vm.ordering.id);
  });
```

But why it doesn't work for Checkbox?

Comment: Have you tried `wrapper.find('bcheckbox-stub')`? `shallowMount` creates a stub for all child components

Comment: hmm I found a strange behaviour. Also I have in this page `TableTh` child component:
```
<TableTh
        width="10%"
        :sorting.sync="ordering.id"
        :ordering-obj="ordering">
        {{ $t.certs.table.codeOfTemplate }}
      </TableTh>
```
and this test passed:
```
it('TableTh props', function () {
    const th = wrapper.find(TableTh);
    expect(th.props().sorting).toBe(wrapper.vm.ordering.id);
  });
```
But why it doesn't work for Checkbox?
By the way `const checkbox = wrapper.find('b-heckbox-stub');` also doesn't work

Comment: What does it show to you if you console.log: 'wrapper.find(Checkbox)' ?